# Premiere vs. Uraufführung

Tags: difference

Am Dresdner Schauspielhaus hängt immer ein großes Poster mit aktuellen Aufführungen. Ich laufe jeden Tag daran vorbei, doch erst heute ist mir aufgefallen, dass auf dem soeben erwähnten Plakat die Wörter *Premiere* und *Uraufführung* in scheinbar zufälliger Reihenfolge benutzt werden. Ich meine, entweder schreibt man konsistent das eine oder das andere, warum die beiden Begriffe für unterschiedliche Theaterstücke durcheinanderbringen?

Gibt es da einen Bedeutungsunterschied?

Comment: Die Premiere kann meines Wissens auch die erste Aufführung eines Stückes an diesem Theater, oder mit dieser Besetzung, sein, Demgegenüber ist die Uraufführugn die erste Aufführung eines Stückes überhaupt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Uraufführung

Zu jeden Werk, das bereits mindestens einmal auf einer Bühne vor Publikum aufgeführt wurde, gibt es genau eine einzige Uraufführung. Das ist jene Aufführung, bei der dieses Werk das allererste Mal überhaupt aufgeführt wurde.

Daher gehört das Datum der Uraufführung, gemeinsam mit dessen Ort, zur Entstehungsgeschichte eines jeden Werkes.

**Beispiele:**

- Beethovens Sinfonie Nr. 9 in d-Moll op. 125: Uraufgeführt am 7. Mai 1824 im Kärntnertortheater in Wien
- Carmina Burana von Carl Orff: Uraufgeführt am 8. Juni 1937 in der Oper zu Frankfurt am Main
- Aida von Giuseppe Verdi: Uraufgeführt am 24. Dezember 1871 in Kairo, Dar Elopera Al Misria

### Premiere

Eine Premiere ist eine der folgenden Aufführungen:

- die erste Aufführung des Werks auf einer bestimmten Bühne.
- die erste Aufführung einer bestimmten Inszenierung eines Stücks (gibt es nur bei Werken, die einer Inszenierung bedürfen, also z.B. Oper, Ballett, Theaterstück; nicht jedoch z.B. bei einem konzertanten Musikstück)
- die erste Aufführung eines bestimmten Werkes durch ein bestimmtes Ensemble.

Die dritte Definition ermöglicht es daher auch, dass an einem bestimmten Haus auch ein und dasselbe Musikstück zu unterschiedlichen Zeiten zwei Premieren-Aufführungen haben kann, nämlich wenn zwei verschiedene Orchester dieses Werk erarbeitet haben. Allerdings wird von dieser dritten Definition nur selten Gebrauch gemacht.

Comment: Fehlt nur noch der Aspekt, dass eine Uraufführung für ein bestimmtes Land oder einen bestimmten Teil der Welt gemeint sein kann (deutsche Uraufführung, amerikanische Uraufführung, http://www1.wdr.de/themen/archiv/stichtag/stichtag7886.html). Aber die Grenzen dafür, was von wem als ein "anderer Teil der Welt" wahrgenommen wird, sind natürlich zeitbedingt. (Sehr schönes Beispiel anhand der drei Jahreszahlen oben!)

Comment: @Dirk: Obwohl auf der von dir verlinkten Seite das Wort »Uraufführung« steht, handelt es sich bei der Aufführung des Musicals im Oktober 1968 in Deutschland *nicht* um eine Uraufführung, sondern um eine Premiere. Hier wurde einfach das falsche Wort benutzt. Die Uraufführung von »Hair« fand am 29. April 1967 im Biltmore Theatre am New Yorker Broadway statt, und nicht ein Jahr später in Deutschland.

Comment: Dass Du das glaubst, geht aus Deiner Antwort hervor, die ich im Übrigen für sehr plausibel und klar halte. Allerdings zählen bei Sprachauslegung nicht nur persönliche Ansichten, sondern auch der allgemeine, mehrheitliche und zeitgemäße Gebrauch muss berücksichtigt werden. Wenn es Belege für die übertragene Bedeutung im Ausdruck "deutsche Uraufführung (von »Hair«)" (ähnlich wie "deutsche Urfassung" z.B. eines Films) gibt, dann sollten wir das akzeptieren. Und der WDR ist keine so schlechte Referenz für deutsche Sprache.

Answer (score 5):

Die Uraufführung ist die erste Aufführung eines Theaterstückes oder anderen Werkes überhaupt. Die Premiere ist die erste Aufführung einer konkreten Inszenierung eines Theaterstückes.

Wenn also ein Plakat eine Uraufführung bewirbt, darfst Du davon ausgehen, dass es sich um ein komplett neu geschriebenes Theaterstück handelt. Eine Premiere kann hingegen auch diejenige eines alten Theaterstückes sein, aber eben in neuer Inszenierung.

Zum Beispiel wurde Goethes Faust 1829 uraufgeführt, aber man wird heute noch Premieren des Stückes finden.

Answer (score 3):

Also historisch gesehen scheint es von der Erstaufführung -im 20ten Jahrhundert- zur Uraufführung und dann neuerdings zur Premiere gekommen zu sein. http://www.textlog.de/schlagworte-urauffuehrung.html

Laut Wikipedia:

Eine **Uraufführung** ist die erste öffentliche Aufführung eines Musikstückes oder Bühnenwerkes. 
Wenn ein Stück oder ein Film bereits an einem anderen Ort gezeigt wurde, spricht man bisweilen von **Erstaufführung** – mit genauerer Spezifikation, etwa deutsche Erstaufführung bzw. deutschsprachige Erstaufführung, Münchener Erstaufführung etc.

Der Begriff **Premiere** steht für die erste Aufführung einer Opern-Inszenierung oder eines Theaterstücks sowie oft auch für die **Uraufführung** bzw. **Erstaufführung** eines Films in einem bestimmten Land. Die erste Aufführung der Neuinszenierung eines bereits früher uraufgeführten Werks wird ebenfalls als **Premiere** bezeichnet.

Es scheint also Uraufführung wirklich/absolut aller erste Aufführung, Premiere ist eher eine "relative" erste Aufführung.

Comment: Please remove. Wikipedia is wrong in this case (or you misunderstood).

Comment: @Dirk i can't see that i misunderstood or that wikipedia is wrong because all other answers are saying the same thing!